# Raspberry Pi BeautifulSoup library not working

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

We are working on a school project where we are trying to use a Raspberry Pi to build a Is-the-bathroom-free monitor.

When we try to run the python script "tolett.py" it says that it can't find the module named "bs4". We have tried all kinds of combinations, not just bs4. What the python script is basically supposed to do is update the status.html file and upload it to dropbox where we will later get the information about whether or not the bathroom is free.

BUT when we run it as non root it goes through, but then we get permission denied '/home/pi/status.html'. So we're screwed both ways. We're stuck and would love some help.

[image: Pictures of the code and terminal messages]

Comment: Have you installed bs4?

Comment: yes we have with the command pip install BeautifulSoup4

Comment: And def the right version to the version of python you are using? See here for example: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=226776

Comment: Yes we use python3 and the script is written in python3

Answer (score 1):

I see two probable causes:

1. The default `pip` is not the Python3 version, but rather Python2. You can check with the command: `pip --version`. In this case you have installed beautifulSoup module for Python2 not Python3. On my Ubuntu system I have an alternative `pip3`, which is for Python3. You can check the existence of `pip3` on your raspberry pi with the command: `which pip3`.
2. You have indeed installed beautifulSoup for Python3, but the path Python3 uses does not contain the directory in which the beautifulSoup module resides. You can check the install location of a *module* with `pip show module_name`. You can check the path of your Python3 interpreter with a Python3 script:

   ```
   import sys
   print(sys.path)
   ```